# How to post a Zapier trigger to the REST Hook Subscribe URL?

Tags: hook, zapier

I'm using Zapier's [REST Hooks](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v1/rest-hooks/). In my Zap, I also have a trigger field that is used to trigger the zap when the condition is met. In my case, the trigger field is "segment" - so as to only trigger the zap when the selected segment is created.

The trouble I'm having is POSTING the selected trigger field to the REST Hook Subscribe URL.

My first thought is to update the "REST Hook Subscribe URL" to be: https://domain.com/api/v1/hooks?filter={{segment}}

Which does work to pass the trigger field as a URL paramater. However, this creates an Error for the other Triggers, because the "segment" field does not exist.

How is this best accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use Zapier [scripting](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v1/scripting/) to manipulate the requests made to your App's API.

The trigger fields are available with the `bundle.trigger_fields` object.  So I passed these in the params during pre_subscribe like so:

```
'use strict';

var Zap = {
pre_subscribe: function(bundle) {    
    return {
    url: bundle.request.url,
    method: bundle.request.method,
    auth: bundle.request.auth,
    headers: bundle.request.headers,
    params: bundle.trigger_fields,
    data: bundle.request.data
    };
}
}
```

That did the trick for me...